# Phrase "to no avail" and commas

Tags: phrases, commas

The phrase "to no avail" describes something that is futile or ineffective.

> His efforts to stop the thief were to no avail.

Commonly, the phrase is separated from the independent clause of the sentence by a comma. Is this a violation, seeing as the phrase is not independent per se?

> She tried to brush the tangles out of her hair, but to no avail.
>
> She tried to brush the tangles out of her hair but to no avail.

Even when writing, I myself would not worry about throwing in the comma as I have never met any reader who finds something to pick at in a sentence like the one above. In a slightly more formal context, would the phrase be connected with or without a comma?

Comment: This is the type of comma that one should put in only if one hears it. Commas denote an intonation contour; if you want the reader to hear it, put in the comma; if you don't want that, don't use it.

Comment: Hi I’m Jim. nice to meet you.  I’d put a comma after *hair* in your sentence above.  ;-)  Having said that, commas are not grammatical and thus cannot be subject to violation- They are elements of style and are designed to improve readability and comprehension.  I think a healthy pause after *hair* is warranted and thus the comma.  If you want readers to read straight through *hair* and on to *but* with no pause then don’t use a comma.

Comment: Yeah, this is a situation where even the "authorities" may waffle.  I would tend to use the comma, but I wouldn't argue that point strongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two British dictionaries define the word, with example sentences, as follows:

> **[avail](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/avail)**
>    *noun* (usually in phrase **of/to no avail**)
>   Use or benefit:
>   *he begged her to reconsider, but to no avail*
>   *My protestations about the lack of evidence of benefit in such procedures were to no avail.*
>   *She was doing a sterling job of trying to wake him up but to no avail.*
>   *After a few frantic phone calls to no avail, the decision to ad-lib was made.*
>   [Note: The corresponding American English entry in this dictionary did not include this usage.]
>
> **[avail](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/avail)**
>    *noun* [uncountable]
>   use, purpose, advantage, or profit:
>   *We tried to persuade her not to resign, but to no avail (= did not succeed).*
>   *My attempts to improve the situation were of little/no avail.*
>   [Note: The corresponding American English entry in this dictionary did not include the word '*avail*' at all.]

You will see that, of the three example sentences terminating in "*but to no avail*", two precede it with a comma, and one doesn't. Personally, I would normally include a comma in that position, because, when speaking the sentence, I would normally pause slightly at that point.  As John Lawler says in his comment, if you want the reader to 'hear' the pause, then include a comma.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've heard "but to no avail"; that sounds awkward to me. I would use:

> She tried to brush the tangles out of her hair, to no avail.

If you want to make it a bit more dramatic:

> She tried to brush the tangles out of her hair — to no avail.

As for your first sentence, I would never say "were to no avail". Maybe it makes sense on a technical level, but it feels weird. I would instead opt for concision:

> His efforts to stop the thief were futile.

It's simpler and avoids any awkwardness. If you *must* use "avail", this sounds better to me:

> His efforts to stop the thief were without avail.

Comment: The phrase "*but to no avail*" is in the British dictionaries - and is perfectly natural & valid. See my answer.

Comment: @TrevorD ah, I was unaware of its use in British English. I've never heard it here (in the US). I suppose OP's final choice will depend on whether American or British English is desired. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Adding ", but" seems redundant. As a British Grammar user, I am familiar with this term and use it often myself, and simply "she tried, to no avail" will always suffice; slowing it down and jamming it up with the obvious ", but" is a little pedantic.